# Python Tkinter with Turtle and Scrollbars

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

I have been having some problems implementing scrollbars into my Tkinter program which uses turtle. I am able to create and add the turtle canvas to my Tkinter program just fine, however, the scrollbars don't seem to fit visually even though they can be dragged. The canvas also starts offset meaning you have to scroll it to the centre every time. Below is an example of this issue.

[image: Broken Scrollbars]

I know that I could use turtles built-in "Scrolledcanvas" however this would mean I am unable to style the scrollbars using ttk. If possible I would remove the scrollbars entirely, and just simply centre the graphics and make them fit the canvas at all times, however, this seemed too complex for me.

I have provided a working example below for anyone to take a look at.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import turtle

root = tk.Tk()

aFrame = tk.Canvas(root)
aFrame.pack()

aCanvas = tk.Canvas(aFrame)
aCanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="")

aScreen = turtle.TurtleScreen(aCanvas)

aXScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(aFrame, orient="horizontal", command=aCanvas.xview)
aXScrollbar.bind("<Configure>",
                 lambda e: aCanvas.configure(
                     scrollregion=aCanvas.bbox("all")
                 ))
aXScrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

aYScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(aFrame, orient="vertical", command=aCanvas.yview)
aYScrollbar.bind("<Configure>",
                 lambda e: aCanvas.configure(
                     scrollregion=aCanvas.bbox("all")
                 ))
aYScrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

aTurtle = turtle.RawTurtle(aScreen)
aTurtle.goto(0, 0)
aTurtle.fillcolor('blue')
aTurtle.begin_fill()
for i in range(4):
    aTurtle.forward(150)
    aTurtle.right(90)
aTurtle.end_fill()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: binding to the `<Configure>` event of the scrollbars seems very strange. What do you think that is accomplishing?

Comment: I found that on another post, it seems to stop the Tkinter graphics from moving outside of the scrollable canvas